# Express in terms of familiar arithmetic functions

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

How can I express the sumation $$h_k(n)=\sum_{d|n, k|d}\mu (d)$$ in terms of familiar arithmetic functions, where $k\in \mathbb{N} $ is fixed?

Answer (score 1):

First, since $k\mid d\mid n\implies k\mid n$, we have

$$h_k(n)=\sum_{k\mid d\mid n}\mu(d)=\begin{cases} 0 & k\nmid n \\[5pt] \sum_{r\mid n/k}\mu(kr) & k\mid n\end{cases}$$

Second, letting $n'$ be the greatest divisor of $n/k$ that is coprime to $k$,

$$\sum_{r\mid n/k}\mu(kr)=\mu(k)\sum_{r\mid n'}\mu(r)=\mu(k)[n'=1],$$

since if $r\mid n/k$ but $(r,k)\ne1$ then $kr$ is not squarefree so the term $\mu(kr)=0$ can be forgotten, and otherwise we know that $\mu$ is multiplicative so that $\mu(kr)=\mu(k)\mu(r)$. Above we use the so-called Iverson bracket notation, where $[P]$ is $1$ if $P$ is true and $0$ if $P$ is false.

The condition $n'=1$ is equivalent to the prime divisors of $n$ being a subset of the prime divisors of $k$, which is itself equivalent to $n\mid k^\infty$. Therefore we conclude

$$h_k(n)=\begin{cases}\mu(k) & k\mid n\mid k^\infty \\ 0 & \rm otherwise.\end{cases} $$